# Light/RayCasting in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, shader

How can I use a shader that interacts with my environment that is not with box2d.

I read this: [Libgdx light without box2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278229/libgdx-light-without-box2d)

Talking about how I could do a circle light fixture with a sprite.
The question I have is: How can I create a ray cast, like from a streetlight (for example).

The sprite shown is a circle, Would I have to create another sprite to deal with this? I want something like this: [image: inlined image]

How would I start this?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more details.  What sort of environment are you rendering?  (2d or 3d?)  What does your code look like to draw the tiles and light source?

Comment: Alright, so I want to do this on a 2D screen.

Comment: I use a TileMap.java file to render and draw my tileset. http://pastebin.com/5vFpLtxE then I render it inside a playstate.