# Java 2D Game Engine, LibGdx lights

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine, 2d-games, light

I have already read a lot of question, about which engine you should use for a 2D Game, but I still have same questions.

I already wrote a little 2d game with libgdx, but my next game should be a bit more advanced. By my first game I used Spritebatches to render it, but when I want lighting, then I read, that you should use Box2d lights for things like this.

The questions is now what fit the best using box2d or spritebatch or should I use a completely different engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big thing of Box2dLights is that it calculates lighting and shadows depending on objects from your Box2d physics (which is also included in libGDX).

Although you *could* use Box2dLights without Box2d if you just want to draw lights without calculated shadows I'd recommend just to use sprites with adapted BlendFunc in this case. You can find a more detailed answer how to do this here in [Libgdx light without box2d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117160/2756574).

So after all it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, will have a look into it.